# Rasterio histogram save as image

Tags: python, rasterio, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I have create some histogram using DEM as dataset and rasterio using `show_hist` to take histogram but I can't find some way to save this histogram as `image.any` idea?

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show_hist
src = rasterio.open("path/to/your/image.tif")
show_hist(
    src, bins=50, lw=0.0, stacked=False, alpha=0.3,
    histtype='stepfilled', title="Histogram")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [`matplotlib.pyplot.savefig()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html) function, which saves the current figure.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show_hist
src = rasterio.open("path/to/your/image.tif")
show_hist(
    src, bins=50, lw=0.0, stacked=False, alpha=0.3,
    histtype='stepfilled', title="Histogram")
plt.savefig('test.png')  # output format is inferred from the extension
```

---

If this does not work, you can always pass an `ax` argument to the `show_hist()` function. Here is an example from the [documentation](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/plotting.html):

```py
>>> fig, (axrgb, axhist) = pyplot.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(14,7))
>>> show(src, ax=axrgb)
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x...>
>>> show_hist(src, bins=50, histtype='stepfilled',
...           lw=0.0, stacked=False, alpha=0.3, ax=axhist)
>>> pyplot.show()
```

Then, you can call the `savefig()` method on the `Figure` object.

```py
>>> fig.savefig('test.png')
```